# Trouble with React SPA Routing

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have the following index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './main/main';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter><Main /></BrowserRouter>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

the following in main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavMenu from "./navmenu";
import Content from "./content";
import './main.css';

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main-layout">
        <div id="main-header">
          <div><img src={(require("./images/ppslogo-small.png"))} alt="eeeee"/></div>
          <div><h2>Lil Test By Me</h2></div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-content">
          <NavMenu />
          <Content />
        </div>
        <div id="main-footer">
          <div>Copyright &copy; 2020. Powered By me.  All Rights Reserved.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

And The following in content.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-dom';

import Dashboard from "../dashboard/dashboard";
import Invoicing from "../invoicing/invoicing";

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/Invoicing" component={Invoicing} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
};
export default Content
```

It it my attempt to create an SPA with the Content component as my target for all my subsequent pages; however, I am clearly doing something wrong as I am getting all kinds of errors all over the place.  Can anyone immediately see what I am doing incorrectly here?

Comment: What errors are you getting (in order). All kinds of errors can be caused be all kinds of issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Route` and `Switch` needs to be imported from `react-router-dom` instead of `react-dom`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from "../dashboard/dashboard";
import Invoicing from "../invoicing/invoicing";

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="/Invoicing" component={Invoicing} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
};
export default Content
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router` and then 
change your content.js code to this.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Route, Switch,  BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import Dashboard from "../dashboard/dashboard";
import Invoicing from "../invoicing/invoicing";

class Content extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/invoicing" component={Invoicing} />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    )
  }
};
export default Content
```

notice that I have added Router above the switch. and changed react-router to react-router-dom and also transformed the routes to lowercase

Comment: I think it is better practice to keep the router provider on the root level.

Comment: I wanted to keep the BrowseRouter on the main root.

Comment: Yes, it is good practice ... I hadn't seen he's Router in the root yet...  thanks for the correction